# Why does QGIS 2.2 Atlas not work?

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have problem with atlas generation in QGIS 2.2.
I'd like to export pdf map with 2 maps window and use coverage layer function.
Atlas doesn't iterate across the features in coverage layer.

First problem is output preview which doesn't work at all.

Anyway when i export map as pdf i have same map for all features.
It seems that atlas can count my features in coverage layer but it can't iterate across it.

I use shp file with points and lines + shp with polygons for coverage layer.

When I try it with same file in QGIS 2.0 everything works fine.
I have installed both version QGIS 2.0 and QGIS 2.2.

Have you ever seen a similar problem as I have or do you have any idea for a solution?

Comment: Atlas generation works fine for me in both 2.0 and 2.2. Preview works fine in 2.2 as well. Attaching your project file might help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For QGIS 2.2, there were made a lot of improvements in the atlas features. On of the new features is that you can now control more than one map with the atlas coverage layer.

In QGIS 2.0 the atlas options would automatically choose one of your map items to control. This no longer happens in QGIS 2.2, since you can choose which maps you want to be controlled by atlas. For that, you must go to each the map item properties and make it atlas controlled.

[image]

From this point on, you will notice that everything will work just fine (including the preview).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes you are right. I just missed this new option in item properties. Now it works.